# count element using Xquery and return both the element name and value

Tags: xml, xquery

I have to count how many times of the authors show in a XML file. Lets say,as attached - [XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM3Gp.jpg)

Frank Manola has appeared 2 times and Tolga Yurek has appeared 1 time.

My desire result is:

**Frank Manola , 2

Tolga Yurek, 1**

I used this code, but I cannot archive it:

**for $a in doc("dblp.xml")/dblp/* let$c := count ($a/author) return ($a/author , $c)**

Result become very weird like this:[unwanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7o5i.jpg)

What error in my code? What can I group and sum them up?

Comment: Please tell us which XQuery version you use as 3.0 and later have a `group` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating several times on the same author. Maybe you should use distinct-values when you loop on the authors?

Something like:

```
for $a in distinct-values(doc("file.xml")//author)
  let $c := count(//author[. = $a])
  return ($a, $c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems doesn't work, got an error "Error:
Stopped at ., 1/103:
[XPTY0019] text(): node expected, xs:untypedAtomic found: "Kurt P. Brown"."

Comment: @Peter, the `$a/text()` should simply be `$a`.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3 you can use `group by` https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by:

```
for $author in doc("dblp.xml")/dblp/*/author
group by $a := $author
return $a || ': ' || count($author)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVe/1